# US citizen residing in Italy

Tags: us-citizens, residency, italy

I have been living in Italy for the last 20 years but I go back to the US every year. I still have a US bank account and have renewed my NJ driver's licence when staying in NJ for a month last time, when staying with my sister.

Recently I received jury duty. How should I reply?

Comment: Does the USA know you're not resident there?

Comment: what are the disqualification options on your jury duty reply form?

Comment: @user16259 how would the USA "know" where any of its citizens lives? There is no registry of US citizens

Comment: @phoog I speculated that US citizens filing tax returns from abroad could be automatically excused from jury service.

Comment: @user16259 usually being out of the jurisdiction of the court is an automatic deferral, and *residing* out of the jurisdiction of the court is disqualifying.  The problem is that renewing her New Jersey driver's license is essentially a claim that she resides in New Jersey, so claiming to the court that she doesn't reside there could cause problems.

Comment: Yes i was  in for a month

Comment: The first question asks if you are a resident of bergen county,  does responding no excludes me from jury duty?